# Await/async reference error

Tags: c#, reference, compiler-errors, async-await

im trying to do some async operation in some function returning string.

```
async private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string output = await thr_calc(this, null);
}

async private Task<string> thr_calc(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     return await zzztest();            
}

string zzztest()
{
    string asd;
    //some stuff here
    return asd;
}
```

But it gives me errors on each string contains words async/await! Im using russian version of ms vs express 2012 for windows desktop, so here is the translation of errors:

> Cannot find all types required by the 'async' modifier. Are you targeting the wrong framework version, or missing a reference to an assembly?

And 2 errors:

> Predefined type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine' is not defined or imported

I cant find that reference. I've tried to use async/await before and it worked fine, now im doing all the same and its not. What I am missing?

Comment: I can give you copy-pasted errors on russian language, will they help you?

Comment: Are you using framework 4.5?

Comment: For reference, if framework<4.5 the error given by the US version is: "Cannot find all types required by the 'async' modifier. Are you targeting the wrong framework version, or missing a reference to an assembly?" So the translation was spot on.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- In thr_calc, use:

  ```
  return zzztest()
  ```
- Also, make sure you've set your project to use .Net 4.5 or later (that's when "async" was introduced)

Comment: That's strange, because it compiles for me. Did you check under the project's properties, under "application", that the framework is 4.5?

Comment: (well it compiles once I assign a value to asd, but I'm sure you'd have no problem fixing that compilation error)

Comment: Actually, ive remembered - this solution was imported from old virtual machine where was framework 4 and old Studio... Thats why those errors show. I changed version required to 4.5 and it compiled sucsessfully. Thanks for quick respond everyone.

Answer (score 9):

On a .NET 4.0 project, I resolved 'Predefined type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine' is not defined or imported' by installing the Microsoft.Bcl.Async package from nuget. In VS's nuget package manager, search for 'bcl' and install the async-looking one.

Answer (score 2):

If `zzztest` is a long running operation, you can do this to run it in a background thread:

```
async private Task<string> thr_calc(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   return await Task.Run<string>(() => zzztest());            
}
```

The above should solve your compile errors as well.

If `zzztest` is NOT a long running operation, then consider NOT using `await` / `async`.